# HtmlAgilityPack node value is correct but InnerText is empty

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse HTML page using HtmlAgilityPack on WindowsPhone 8 application. This is the part of HTML code I need to parse and populate list:

```
<div class="clslist">
   <select name="administrative_unit_id">
      <option value="" selected="selected">All cities</option>
      <option value='1'>City 1</option>
      <option value='2'>City 2</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

I wrote this code to parse HTML:

```
listCities = New ObservableCollection(Of city) 
For Each node In htmlDok.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//select[starts-with(@name, administrative_unit_id)]").Descendants("option")
   Dim cty As New city
   cty.ctyId = node.Attributes("value").Value
   cty.desc = node.InnerText
   listCities.Add(cty)
Next
```

When I run application I see that cty.ctyId gets correct values but cty.desc is always empty.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Try to use cty.Value instead of cty.InnerText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inner text of option tags are *blank* by default. Just add

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option")
```

before loading HtmlDocument.